# Claim based authentication in webrequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, sharepoint, claims-based-identity, federated-identity

How a webrequest can make between these twi applications...

[image: Diagram]
sample code:

```
HttpWebRequest webRqst = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
webRqst.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
webRqst.Method = "GET";
webRqst.Accept = "*/*";
webRqst.KeepAlive = true;
 using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                            }
                         }
                }
```

While I am making a request it always looking for the login page. My response is always the login form in the STS. Thank you.

Comment: while I make the request, I got the response as login page to the STS server. applicationB always redirect to the STS server for token. No reuse of token here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/09/using-the-jwt-handler-for-implementing-poor-man-s-delegation-actas/

Comment: let me check it. Thank you for our kind. I was on this code for the last 2 weeks.